# I am trying to click on search button using class but it is clicking some other button which has same class name. Y it is clicking on other button

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Search button html code.

```
<button type="button" class="btn form-control customSelect dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle="" ng-disabled="disabled" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                                <span class="custom-text ng-binding">Initial Status</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                                                            </button>
```

Other button html code

```
<button type="button" class="btn form-control customSelect dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle="" ng-disabled="disabled" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <span class="custom-text ng-binding">No Filter</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                                        </button>
```

Please help me.

Comment: how are you firing click on class, could you add some code?

Comment: I added both  buttons full code, am doing in protractor. @PankajParkar Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
var searchbtn = element.all(by.css('.btn')).get(0);
searchbtn.click();
```

or

```
var searchbtn = element.all(by.type('button')).get(0);
searchbtn.click();
```

Here get(0) means first button.

Comment: @raghavendrat note that `get(0)` can be replaced with `first()`.

Comment: @alecxe yes i tried using first() it 's worked. Thanks